# How to get id of element in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` with a local file embedded. I don't know how to get a specific element in this document.
I have tried `window.top.document.getElementById('numPages')` and `$("#myiframe").contents().find("#numPages")` to get element with an id of numPages.

Comment: Is `viewer.html` on the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: Yes, it on same domain.

Comment: Also confusing as to how many iframes there are based on first sentence. Can be interpreted as nested iframes or just one iframe total

Comment: And is there any ajax loaded content in the inner page? And where do you call your code? are you waiting for onload event in iframe? Show all relevant code

Comment: No, i don't use ajax. It is pdfJs, i use pdfJs to display pdf file.

Comment: Well that should have been mentioned in question along with all the relevant code. jsPdf will need time to count the pages probably and render your element. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.contentDocument`
eg:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame"),
    idocument = iframe.contentDocument
    // Use idocument instead of document
```

Comment: when i use `var numPages = idocument.getElementById('numPages');`  i see in console log return null value.

Comment: Are you sure that numPages exists?

Comment: Yes, it exists in my viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the element in plain javascript try using contentWindow

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.document.body.getElementById('numPages');
```

Answer (score 0):

By this way, You can get frame id and set css property inside frame element. It'll work 100%.

```
<script>
            window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
                let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
                var iframevar = document.getElementById(iframe.id);
                var elmnt = iframevar.contentWindow.document.getElementById("header_27");
                elmnt.style.color = 'black';
                var elmnt = iframevar.contentWindow.document.getElementById("header_59");
                elmnt.style.color = 'black';
    
            }
        </script>
```